# How set time zone when running the code in R?

Tags: r, time

I am currently located in `"Europe/Helsinki"` time zone and want to put a code running through a server in the USA and has `"America/New_York"` timezone.
When I run a code on my computer, I frequently use `Sys.time()` and `Sys.Date()` functions. I know that when put the code run on the server it will use `"America/New_York"` timezone in these two functions, however, my code logic assumes the `"Europe/Helsinki"` time zone. How can I do that every time `Sys.time()` and `Sys.Date()` will show output in `"Europe/Helsinki"` time zone

I found that using `options(tz="Europe/Helsinki")`  before running a full code could solve the problem, but not sure that it will help.
Also was found a solution in `lubridate` package `with_tz(Sys.time(), "Europe/Tallinn")`, however if use `with_tz(Sys.Date(), "Europe/Tallinn")` the output also shows time `03:00:00 EEST`. I also tried `as.POSIXct(with_tz(Sys.Date(), "Europe/Helsinki"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "Europe/Helsinki")`, but this time is also shown up.

What is better to use in my case?

Example:

```
  df<-subset(df, date == Sys.Date())

  if(hour(Sys.time()) >=9  & hour(Sys.time()) <= 18){
    
    DOtask1
  } 
  else {
    DOtask2
  }
```

Comment: Not sure which is your actual use case. You have shown a couple of ways to solve it, but didn't explain why they might not work. Please, add some details on what you do with this `Sys.time()` calls.

Comment: @nicola I added an example of my code to the question. I showed 2 examples: 1) with `options()`, I may suspect that it got some roots to the folder where R is installed or environment is stored (so for server It might not working) 2) in `lubridate` I stressed that `Sys.Date()` is not working properly

Comment: You can change the timezone of a `POSIXct` object `x` with something like `attr(x,"tzone")<-"Europe/Helsinki"`.